# Can't update Proliant ML350 Intelligent Provisioning/Install Server 2012 R2

Tags: hp-proliant

I have been struggling since Friday to get HP Intelligent Provisioning working on a Hp Proliant ML350e Gen8. I want to install server 2012 R2 but for the life of me I cant seem to get this working.

**What I've done:** I have to mention I tried installing with just the windows CD but I get a BOD when it first needs to boot. I assume this has to do with the raid controller but I have tied every version of the drivers I could find and it still BOD after first boot. It has B120i Array controller)

After hours of struggle I have managed to update Intelligent Provisioning to V1.50 but no luck and the V1.61(b) upgrade just makes as if it upgrades and when I restart I am still stuck at V1.50.

**Question:** Can someone please point me to a working version (possibly 1.60 so I can try to upgrade from there) or a possible solutions to this headache?

Comment: Can you explain how you updated Intelligent Provisioning?

Comment: I downloaded the V1.6.1(b) iso from HP's site (After allot of searching) and that boots and says it successfully updates the Intelligent Provisioning but when I restart it was still stuck at V1.30. I then downloaded the V1.50 iso and tryied again. This time it updated but still would not update to V1.61(b)

Answer (score 1):

- It's not necessary to use Intelligent Provisioning in order to install an operating system on Gen8/Gen9 ProLiant servers. The [HP Dynamic Smart Array driver](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5260585&swItemId=MTX_09a49efe5daf4d74bb214f355d&swEnvOid=4138#tab1) is available separately. I'd imaging you can slipstream this into the installation.
- Some systems ship with old firmware and outdated Intelligent Provisioning software. Download the current [Intelligent Provisioning ISO](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5228284&swItemId=MTX_5a7aecd1f0534d3ebf7214be7d&swEnvOid=4168#tab2) from HP. You can burn this to disk or mount via ILO.
- Your Intelligent Provisioning loads. You should probably use it to update your system's firmware *before* you run the OS installer.

Comment: Tried that already. V2.01 does not support my Gen 8 server. I have also tried the array drivers and I can load the OS but when it restarts to boot for the first time I get a BOD

Comment: @Griffin I suggested you upgrade your server's firmware. That means: BIOS, RAID controller, NIC, disks... You can use Intelligent Provisioning to do that. Try that first, then run your installation.